Run-time error -2147023170 (800706be): Automation error, the remote procedure call failed
I am getting this above-mentioned error on running. The purpose of this code is to take values from an Excel sheet and put two values from the sheet into the website then extract results from web into a sheet.
It shows error on this line Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4"
I also used READYSTATE_COMPLETE it did not work too.
Sub WebAutomation()
 
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim html As Object
    Dim inputFilePath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim resultSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim number1 As String
    Dim number2 As String
    Dim additionResult As String
    Dim subtractionResult As String
    Dim multiplicationResult As String
    Dim divisionResult As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim startTime As Single
 
    ' Define the input file path and open the workbook
    inputFilePath = "C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Calculator.xlsx" ' Change this path to your actual file path
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(inputFilePath)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Create a new sheet for results
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Sheets("Results").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set resultSheet = wb.Sheets.Add
    resultSheet.Name = "Results"
    resultSheet.Range("A1:F1").Value = Array("Number 1", "Number 2", "Addition", "Subtraction", "Multiplication", "Division")
    
    ' Initialize IE
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.FullScreen = True ' Maximize the browser window
    
    ' Get the last row of data
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row of the input data
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming the first row is headers
        number1 = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        number2 = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        
        ' Navigate to the web page
        ie.Navigate "https://www.automationandagile.com/p/demo-page.html"
        
        ' Wait for the page to load
        Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        
        ' Wait for the input element to be available
        startTime = Timer
        Do While Timer - startTime < 10
            On Error Resume Next
            Set html = ie.document
            If Not html Is Nothing Then
                If Not html.getElementById("num1") Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
            DoEvents
        Loop
        
        If html Is Nothing Or html.getElementById("num1") Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Failed to load the webpage or find the input elements.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ' Fill the form and submit
        html.getElementById("num1").Value = number1
        html.getElementById("num2").Value = number2
        html.getElementById("btnCalculate").Click
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02") ' Wait for results to load
        
        ' Retrieve results
        On Error Resume Next
        additionResult = html.getElementById("lblAdd").innerText
        subtractionResult = html.getElementById("lblSub").innerText
        multiplicationResult = html.getElementById("lblMult").innerText
        divisionResult = html.getElementById("lblDiv").innerText
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' Store the results in the results sheet
        resultSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = number1
        resultSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = number2
        resultSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = additionResult
        resultSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = subtractionResult
        resultSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value = multiplicationResult
        resultSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = divisionResult
    Next i
    
    ' Close IE
    ie.Quit
    
    ' Save the workbook with results
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=Left(inputFilePath, InStrRev(inputFilePath, ".") - 1) & "_results.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    wb.Close
    
    MsgBox "Data extraction and calculation completed!", vbInformation
 
End Sub


I've taken your code and removed everything except the I.E. stuff and it works fine here. Can't recreate.

Does IE open, have you stepped through?

Why do you load the page again for each calculation? You need the page only once and then you can fill the input fields again for each calculation.

Thanks everyone for your valuable replies. This code is running after enabling the reference "AccessibilityCplAdmin 1.0 Type Library"
